# sum for a chirp signal

Tags: matlab

I have a chirp signal. In Matlab, the command is `s=chirp(t,f0,t1,f1)`. I make the following sum with Matlab: `y=rand(1,size(s,2))+s;`

Here is my question:
What is the theoretical equation for `y`? I know the expression of `s`.

Comment: The equation you are looking for is $y = \alpha x + \beta \mathcal{U}(u,v)$ where $\alpha, \beta$ depend on the relative powers of the two sequences and $u,v$ determine the range of `rand`... Also, $x$ you seem to have a good idea of (the `chirp` function). But...is this really what your question is about (?).

Comment: the use of rand and not randn is unusual